# .htaccess rewriting and redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a site on a new shared server, so the domain name is not active. I am using a temporary url, something like 
http://100.75.100.120/~mywebsite

I am changing a lot of .html files into .php and am also hiding the file suffix in the links to the pages. So I need help with some rewrite/redirect rules.

Can someone help me with the rules so that when someone looks for the old .html file, they are shown the .php file. And when they look for the file without a suffix they are shown the .php file without revealing the suffix?

I have tried lots of different things, but really don't know what I am doing. Doing it in this temp url environment makes it more difficult. At the moment I am writing a rule for each page eg

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html http://100.75.100.120/~mywebsite
RewriteRule ^other/$ http://100.75.100.120/~mywebsite/other.php [R=301,L]
# ... and many more
```

I am sure there would be a much better way. Many thanks.

Another problem I have come across is there are directories with the same names as some of the php files.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect each request with

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://100.75.100.120/~mywebsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, firstly it was redirecting to the root of the server, so I changed what you wrote to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://100.75.100.120/~mywebsite/$1 [R=301,L]` and it now gives an error "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: @ChrisParker oh i fogot your subdirectory. For your other problem with the redirect see this: https://support.mozilla.org/sv/questions/938531

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob, but the "page not redirecting properly" is nothing to do with Cookies, and is caused by that line in the .htaccess file.